# Javascript - Get variable value from external js file

Tags: javascript

i am working like bookmark plugin using external js/css files.

```
 <a class="add-menu-text" href="javascript: (function (5) {   
var jsCode = document.createElement('script'); 
jsCode.setAttribute('src','http://mywebsite.com/javascripts/bookmark.js'); 
document.body.appendChild(jsCode); }());">
 Bookmark 
</a>
```

But here i want to pass variable and get the variable in external file (bookmark.js).

I drag and drop the "Bookmark" in toolbar. once i click the "Bookmark" in tool bar i need to get the variable in external website.(bookmark.js).

I need to get the value(5) in bookmark.js

Comment: I drag and drop the  "Bookmark"  in toolbar. once i click the "Bookmark" in tool bar  i need to get the variable in external website.(bookmark.js).

Answer (score 1):

You can load external script with the [`jQuery.getScript()` function](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)

```
$.getScript( "bookmark.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
  //Data will contain the returned data of your script
});
```

Comment: What about using vanilla JS (not jQuery)? Is there a way to do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Just create variable outside of any functions and it should be available from another js files.

```
var foo = 'bar'
```

You may also save variable as a property of window object, which is the root of all objects in DOM, but this approach is not recommended

```
window.foo = 'bar'
```

after that, foo var may be accessed in two ways

```
window.foo
```

or just

```
foo
```

Although I'd recommend to stick with the first approach - general rule is to try to keep your variables as local as possible.

Here is more info about JS variable scopes
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp
http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/

I'd highly advice you to read this articles(and maybe some more) on the topic - JS scoping is a tricky thing.